# WPF C# не отображается image после компиляции

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения, xaml

Есть простой код XAML. [image: Элемент Image отображается только в IDE.]
Когда я задаю элемент  в редакторе кода, картинка на превью моей программы отображается. После компиляции - она пропадает. Файл с нужным изображением лежит в ресурсах проекта.

```
<Window x:Class="QuitzMaker.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QuitzMaker"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Викториния - создавай и проходи викторины!" Height="600" Width="800">
    
    <Grid UseLayoutRounding="True">
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="/Resources/MainBackground.jpg" />
        <Border CornerRadius="15" Background="#a14b16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="350" Width="535">
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="8" BlurRadius="8" Color="#945026"/>
            </Border.Effect>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Я не так уж и долго занимаюсь программированием, постарайтесь пожалуйста объяснить попроще=)
Заранее большое и сердечное спасибо.

Comment: Для картинки поставьте Build Action = Resource, в пути к ней уберите в начале /, `Source="Resources/MainBackground.jpg"`

Comment: папку с изображениями надо копировать к exe-файлу. когда запускаете из студии, у вас другой рабочий каталог. копирование настраивается в свойствах файла в проекте (Build Action: Resource, Copy To Output Directory: Copy if newer)

Comment: А где ставится этот Build Action?

Comment: В обозревателе решения выбрать файл и в свойствах установить.

Comment: Поставил, теперь InitializeComponent(); ошибка CS0103

Comment: Все заработало, большое спасибо!